# Who/what replaced the Dementors at Azkaban?

Tags: harry-potter, dementors, azkaban

It would be foolish to trust the Dementors after they sided with Voldemort, but somebody's got to guard Azkaban- was this ever adressed?

Comment: Laser fences, maybe?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the [Azkaban entry on Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/azkaban), Kingsley gets rid of the Dementors and replaces them with Auror guards:

> Under Kingsley Shacklebolt, Azkaban was purged of Dementors. While it remains in use as a prison, the guards are now Aurors, who are regularly rotated from the mainland. There has been no breakout since this new system was introduced.

We can only speculate on where they went after this, since Azkaban seems to be the only place they've ever called home; in fact it's strongly implied that they were *created* on that island.

Comment: Any information on how Azkaban was purged?

Comment: @maguirenumber6 Not that I've been able to find; I assume that, with proper motivation, the Auror corps would be able to drive them off, although I'm unclear on where'd they go instead

Comment: Perhaps they had discovered or devised was a way to destroy them, or contain them somehow.

Comment: A lot of dementors were sent to "protect" Hogwarts from Sirius Black (and scattered after Harry's Patronus at the end of book three), then Umbridge appropriated a few more to harass Dudley. There can't have been very many left in Azkaban anyway (and likely even most of those were sent on assorted Death Eater activities).

Comment: @JanuaryFirst-of-May The Pottermore article on Azkaban says there were thousands of them in Azkaban. The ones who were stationed around the country when looking for Sirius and the ones Umbridge appropriated would likely have returned there afterwards anyway.

Comment: Seems like a terrible thing to do to just drive them off. There must have been a considerable number of them and the difficulty of the Patronus charm makes it very hard to defend against them, so just evicting them from Azkaban is a recipe for disaster and despair for some unfortunate souls in a somewhat near proximity.

Comment: @Mainstroke Indeed; one hopes that Kingsley had thought of that, but of course we have no information